# tkinter window/frame blinks on button click

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a tkinter program with a start/stop button to enter and exit an infinite loop that logs to a text logger widget. I cannot for the life of me figure out why, but only when the start *button* is pressed, the frame blinks/flashes, but the function runs fine. When I select start from the file menu, there is no flash... any ideas as to why this may be? Is it a bug in my code?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from tkinter import ttk
import logging


def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    b1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    b1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()


class TextHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, text):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Store a reference to the Text it will log to
        self.text = text

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)

        def append():
            self.text.configure(state='normal')
            self.text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
            self.text.configure(state='disabled')
            # Autoscroll to the bottom
            self.text.yview(tk.END)

        # This is necessary because we can't modify the Text from other threads
        self.text.after(0, append)

    def create(self, num):
        # Create textLogger
        topframe = tk.Frame(root)
        topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        if num == 0:
            st = tkst.ScrolledText(topframe, state='disabled')
            st.configure(font='TkFixedFont')

            st.pack()

            self.text_handler = TextHandler(st)

            # Add the handler to logger
            self.logger = logging.getLogger()
            self.logger.addHandler(self.text_handler)
            print(num)

        else:
            # Add the handler to logger
            self.logger = logging.getLogger()
            print(num)


def stop():
    root.flag = False


def loop():
    th = TextHandler("none")
    th.create(1)

    def start():
        if root.flag:
            th.logger.error("error")
            root.after(1000, start)
        else:
            th.logger.error("Loop stopped")
            root.flag = True
            return
    start()



class HomePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #logger and main loop
        th = TextHandler("none")
        th.create(0)
        root.flag = True

        bottomframe = tk.Frame(root)
        bottomframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        topframe = tk.Frame(root)
        topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        topframe = tk.Frame(root)
        topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        # Create taskbar/menu
        taskbar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=taskbar)

        file = tk.Menu(taskbar)
        file.add_command(label="Run", command=loop)
        file.add_command(label="Stop", command=stop)
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label="Settings", command=lambda: popupmsg("Coming \"soon\"..."))
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label="Quit", command=quit)
        taskbar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        startButton = tk.Button(bottomframe, text="Start", command=loop)
        startButton.pack()

        stopButton = tk.Button(bottomframe, text="Stop",  command=stop)
        stopButton.pack()

        exitButton = tk.Button(bottomframe, text="Exit",  command=quit)
        exitButton.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = HomePage(root)
    root.wm_title("Scraper")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't look close enough to see why and where in the code, but on button press, your window slightly resizes (gets bigger vertically). That most likely causes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure why, but adjusting my code like so has fixed this screen blink.

I moved the `stop` and `loop` functions into the `TextHandler` class as methods. This allowed me to remove the second call to `TextHandler` and the `create` method that was in the `loop` function. I also now have no need for a second argument in the `create` method (was using it as a sort of flag), so that was removed.

I'm guessing the flash was this second call whenever the start button was being clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from tkinter import ttk
import logging


def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("!")
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    b1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    b1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()


class TextHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, text):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Store a reference to the Text it will log to
        self.text = text

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)

        def append():
            self.text.configure(state='normal')
            self.text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
            self.text.configure(state='disabled')
            # Autoscroll to the bottom
            self.text.yview(tk.END)

        # This is necessary because we can't modify the Text from other threads
        self.text.after(0, append)

    def create(self):
        # Create textLogger
        topframe = tk.Frame(root)
        topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        st = tkst.ScrolledText(topframe, state='disabled')
        st.configure(font='TkFixedFont')

        st.pack()

        self.text_handler = TextHandler(st)

        # Add the handler to logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.addHandler(self.text_handler)

    def stop(self):
        root.flag = False

    def loop(self):
        def start():
            if root.flag:
                self.logger.error("error")
                root.after(1000, start)
            else:
                self.logger.error("Loop stopped")
                root.flag = True
                return
        start()


class HomePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #logger and main loop
        th = TextHandler("none")
        th.create()
        root.flag = True

        bottomframe = tk.Frame(root)
        bottomframe.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        topframe = tk.Frame(root)
        topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        topframe = tk.Frame(root)
        topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        # Create taskbar/menu
        taskbar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=taskbar)

        file = tk.Menu(taskbar)
        file.add_command(label="Run", command=lambda: th.loop())
        file.add_command(label="Stop", command=lambda: th.loop())
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label="Settings", command=lambda: popupmsg("Coming \"soon\"..."))
        file.add_separator()
        file.add_command(label="Quit", command=quit)
        taskbar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

        startButton = tk.Button(text="Start", command=lambda: th.loop())
        startButton.pack()

        stopButton = tk.Button(text="Stop",  command=lambda: th.stop())
        stopButton.pack()

        exitButton = tk.Button(text="Exit",  command=quit)
        exitButton.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = HomePage(root)
    root.wm_title("Scraper")
    root.mainloop()
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This isn't a very useful answer. The reader is required to compare the code line-by-line looking for a difference. You should explain what you changed.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Guilty as charged. Honestly since this post garnered little to no interest and not even a comment yet I figured posting something was better than nothing. But that was laziness. Hopefully it's better now.